# Adding default query to all router links in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to find a way to add default `query` to all `router-link`s on a page (in all components that it has)?

For example, I want all links on a page to end with argument: `utm_campaign=from_our_friends`.

And this page uses components that are also used by other pages.

Comment: Can you provide some more context around the **why**? If for instance it's because you want to track every pageview for the session that originated with that campaign, there are other ways

Comment: @Ohgodwhy , yes, I'm trying to know where to users go from one certain page with `utm` args. And that page uses common components that have router links

Comment: So to be clear it's the links going out from the landing page you wish to track as opposed to the entire navigation experience?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy exacty. In other words, I want to pass default query to all possible router-links on a certain page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by @Majed Badawi, I ended up applying this solution:

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    const query = {
        ...to.query,
        utm_campaign: 'from_our_friends'
    };
    if (!to.query.utm_campaign) { // otherwise you'll get 'infinite redirection' error
        next({ path: to.path, query });
    } else {
        next()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a navigation guard to the page component that adds an extra query param to the next destination:

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  const query = { ...to.query, utm_campaign: "from_our_friends" };
  next({ query });
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it WORKS. I was almost sure that I should use `beforeRouteLeave` or `beforeRouteUpdate`, but I couldn't find a way to make it work as needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've discovered another problem. 
With `next({ query })` it adds args to the URL, but doesn't change the path to the page.
If I use `next({ path: to.path, query})`, then I get `infinite redirection` error.
Do you have any idea how to fix this @Majed Badawi ?

Comment: Never mind. I found the solution. I'll update my question adding the fix.